# How to connect MT4 and Python?

Tags: python, mql4, metatrader4

I am a trading EA developer.
I have created a prediction model in python.
And I want to connect MT4 with my model.
I know I can use websocket, but I don't know the details.
Please help me.

https://www.mtsocketapi.com/doc4/API/commands.html
I am using this for my code.
But it is very expensive and can't do what I want.
So I want to create a socket to connect with python.